# PBW / Gröbner basis analog for quadratic cooperads

Tags: operads

Suppose we work with symmetric sequences over a suitable monoidal category. 
Given quadratic data $(E,R)$ PBW and Gröbner bases are of great practical importance to understand the quadratic operad $\mathcal{P}(E,R)$.

I wonder if there are analogs to understand the quadratic cooperad $C(E,R)$ of that quadratic data?